# How to remove "next" option in pagination script when there are no further entries to show?

Tags: php, pagination

I have this script that I have posted a bunch of times but was never able to explain clearly how it was working.  But now I can, so here it is.  I am trying to show the option to see "next" only when there are more entries to be shown.

```
  $result =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%$q%' 
  OR field2 LIKE '%$q%' OR field3 LIKE '%$q%' OR field4 LIKE '%$q%'");


  $num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result);

//check if the starting row variable was passed in the URL or not
if (!isset($_GET['pg']) or !is_numeric($_GET['pg'])) {
  //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $startrow = 0;
  //otherwise we take the value from the URL
} else {
  $startrow = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pg']);
}

$sql = "SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM table WHERE
user_id='$id' limit $startrow, 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

if ($result == "") {
  echo "";
}

echo "";

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0) {
  print("");
} elseif($rows > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $field1 = $row['field1'];
    $field2 = $row['field2'];
    $field3 = $row['field3'];
    $field4 = $row['field4'];

    print("");
  }
}

if($num_rows1 > 10) {
  echo '<a id=pg href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($startrow+10).'&q='.($q).'"> Next</a>';
} 

$prev = $startrow - 10;

//only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
if ($prev >= 0) {
  echo '<a id=pgnvg2 href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.$prev.'&q='.($q).'">
  Previous</a>';
}
```

Comment: I am not able to see the assignment on the variable `$num_rows1` that you are checking in your `if condition for next`

Comment: sorry was skipped.  there now.

Answer (score 2):

Pagination:

```
 Total Items
 Items per Page
 Current Page
```

You only need to show the next navigation if:

```
 Total Items >= Items per Page * (Current Page + 1)
```

That simple it is.

Comment: can you show me in the query format? i am not sure if i am getting it right.. thanks.

Comment: That's unrelated to a query (if you have `Total Items`). You have `Total Items`, don't you?

Comment: @AAA: But you're running a different where clause to obtain that, then to obtaining the paged data fragment later on. That won't work, you see the logical problem? You get the count of something else then you display.

Comment: OK i see what you are talking about.  Those two query results wont match.  So how can i get the count from the main query and get rid of $num_rows1?

Comment: If `$num_rows1` is `Total Items` you can not get rid of it. You will need it.

Comment: i am lost.  not sure how to do this now.  looking for other scritps.

Comment: and by thew way the pg is not for page its for the amount of rows that should be shown next.